# Как добавить путь в переменную окружения %PATH% на Windows?

Tags: windows, path

Как добавить что-то в путь (PATH или system PATH)? Что такое %PATH% и %что-то%?

Вот примеры:

> 1. Add the following string to the `PATH`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake
>      2.8\bin`.
> 2. Do you have make in your `%PATH%` environment variable? On my system, I need to add `%MINGW_DIR%\bin` to `%PATH%`.
> 3. Add `C:<Qt_directory>/mingw/bin` to the system `PATH`.

Я так понимаю, что надо зайти в <kbd>Свойства системы → Дополнительно → Переменные среды...</kbd>

А потом, если говориться про PATH, то добавить в «Переменные среды пользователя такого-то», а если system PATH, то «Системные переменные».

Потом нужно нажать «Создать». Что вписывать в «Имя переменной»? В значение переменной надо записать те строки, которые даны в указании, так?

`Qt\_\_directory` — это, наверно, путь до папки с Qt. Между двумя `%` тоже путь до папки? `%PATH%` и `%MINGW_DIR%` — это одно и тоже, если `PATH` понимают как путь к MinGW?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да, верно, нужно зайти в <kbd>Свойства системы → Дополнительно → Переменные среды</kbd>. Там уже будут переменные PATH. Одна для текущего пользователя, вторая — общесистемная. Просто кликаете на них и добавляете нужный путь через точку с запятой.

[image: Экранный снимок диалога «Environment Variables» в режиме радактирования переменной окружения PATH]

Как вариант, можно написать командный скрипт, в котором будет изменяться переменная окружения. При этом она может менять глобально для всей системы, текущей сессии, так и внутри конкретно той командной оболочки, в которой этот командный скрипт запущен. Смотрите детали в статье «[Update Windows Path Environment Variable](http://www.powercram.com/2011/12/update-windows-path-environment.html)»<sup>[[архив](https://web.archive.org/web/20160819090718/http://www.powercram.com/2011/12/update-windows-path-environment.html)]</sup>.

Comment: Что значит %PATH% на вашем скриншоте в Variable value? И что значит %PATH%/%MINGW_DIR%? Путь к какой-то программе/папке?

Comment: %PATH% - это текущее значение переменной PATH.
Т.е. формулировка PATH = "%PATH%; c:\cygwin\bin" означает "добавить к PATH каталог C:\cygwin\bin"

%MINGW_DIR% - это соответственно значение переменной окружения MINGW_DIR