# Ошибка: «"python" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом»

Tags: python, windows

Хочу запустить программу на python из командной строки, но получаю ошибку: "python" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. (В переменную path я прописала путь до python.exe, но это не помогло)

echo %PATH% выдает:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Sony\VAIO Improvement;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO BIOS Data Transfer Utility\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\; C:\Python34; C:\Python
34\Scripts;C:\Users\александра\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-4.9.2-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-rev1\mingw32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\; C:\Python34\; C:\Python34\Scripts
```

Comment: Значит не так прописали или ком.строка не перезапущена после прописывания.

Comment: Прописала просто C:\Python34. В этой папке и лежит python.exe. Командную строку перезапускала.

Comment: @Александра в командной строка наберите `set path` и убедитесь что `C:\Python34` там есть.

Comment: Скорее всего, синтаксис %PATH нарушен, когда прописывали. Может быть, "С" русская :)

Comment: @PetrAbdulin там только C:\Python27

Comment: @Александра значит что-то вы не там или не так прописали.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin а нет, есть, не увидела

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильно указаны пути к интерпретатору python в переменной окружения `%PATH%`

```
x86)\Google\google_appengine\; C:\Python34\; C:\Python34\Scripts
```

После разделяющей `;` и перед `C:\Python34\` стоит пробел, которого быть не должно.

Answer (score 6):

Если `C:\Python34\python.exe` работает с командной строки, то достаточно добавить `C:\Python34` директорию в `%PATH%`.

[Как добавить в переменную окружения PATH путь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/153628/23044)

Ещё полезно `C:\Python34\Scripts` добавить, чтобы дополнительные скрипты тоже в пути были.

Если на машине установлено несколько версий Питона, то удобно [`py` утилитой](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) пользоваться, чтобы вручную и автоматически (по умолчанию или через shebang (`#!`)) можно было выбирать версию.

Comment: У меня C:\Python34\python.exe работает с командной строки. В PATH я добавила и C:\Python34, и C:\Python34\Scripts, но python все равно не работает с командной строки.

Comment: Что `echo %PATH%` показывает?

Comment: Там много всего, включая C:\Python34 и C:\Python34\Scripts

Comment: @Александра: мне не нужна интерпретация. Чтобы понять, есть ли проблема с %PATH%, мне нужно точное значение (буквально copy-paste) -- можно для отладки временно удалить всё, кроме путей с Питоном, убедиться что по-прежнему `python` ту же ошибку выдаёт в той же консоле, где `echo %PATH%` выполняется и опубликовать здесь (в вопросе) *точный* (как есть)  результат `echo %PATH%` команды.

Comment: Добавила в вопрос