# Проблема при установке Pygame через pip

Tags: python, pip, pygame

Пробую установить библиотеку Pygame для Python через pip. Запускаю командную строку и пишу:

```
pip install pygame
```

Но происходит ошибка:

```
"pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Версия Python 3.7, pip установлен, но установить Pygame всё равно не получается. Решения своей проблемы не нашёл. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: "_Решения своей проблемы на сайте не нашёл._" - На каком сайте?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка: «"python" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439533/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-python-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80)

Comment: На сайте Stack Overflow

Comment: На какой сайте решение проблемы не нашел?

Comment: Нет, это не похоже на решение проблемы

Comment: Нет, очень даже похоже.

Comment: Тогда я не совсем понимаю, как же мне всё таки установить библиотеку. Не могли бы вы мне объяснить немного поподробнее

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93555/discussion-between-minik-and-).

Comment: Проверьте, что у Вас в переменной окружения PATH. Там должны быть прописаны 2 каталога. Если, например, у меня Python установлен в `C:\Tools\Python36-64`, то в PATH должно быть `C:\Tools\Python36_64\Scripts\;C:\Tools\Python36_64\;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Галочку в установщике python'a Поставь (там написанно (add to PATH) примерно)