# Почему не запускается Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

У меня вот какая проблема:
ПО у меня windows 8, установлен Jupyter Notebook который я запускаю через командную строку командой: python -m notebook всё шло прекрасно до вчерашнего дня, когда я установил последнюю версию Python 3.11 и потом сдуру взял и удалил все старые версии Python через программу Soft Organizer со всеми следами. Теперь при запуске Jupyter Notebook из командной строки: C:\User\Master>python -m notebook выдаёт следующее: "python" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Jupyter Notebook у меня установлен без Anaconda. Если кто-нибудь имел такую проблему, прошу поделиться, как это исправить.
Спасибо

Comment: Пусть к python.exe добавьте в переменную окружения PATH. Потом установите jupyter notebook для этой версии python.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка: «"python" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439533/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-python-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Можно ли по подробнее?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `python` использовать команду `python3.11`

Comment: @Vlad63, во втором комментарии по ссылке описано как.

Comment: Выполнить точно так, как там написано? Один в один?

Comment: Попробовал выполнить в точно, как написано по ссылке, пишет, что системе не удаётся найти указанный путь. По второму пожеланию, пробовал команду python3.11 результат тот же

Comment: @Vlad63 не один в один, нужно указать путь, где у вас фактически python установлен. Проще наверное удалить и переустновить заново с установленной галкой "Add to PATH".

Comment: Для insolor: Всё получилось так, как ВЫ рекомендовали! Низкий Вам поклон! Я полностью всё удалил, а потом выполнил: "Проще наверное удалить и переустановить заново с установленной галкой "Add to PATH"".