# Команда from PyQt4 import QtCore" выдает ошибку

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

Команда `from PyQt4 import QtCore` не дает никаких признаков, лишь выдает ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       from PyQt4 import QtCore
>    ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

`import PyQt4` - работает. Помогите решить пожалуйста.

Версия Python 3.5.2, версия PyQt 4.11.4

Comment: В переменной `PATH` должны быть пути как к `PyQt`, так и к `.../Qt/.../bin`. Проверьте их наличие.

Comment: @mkkik в наличии нет bin

Comment: надо [добавить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/153628/207200).

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте есть ли на вашем windows(если вы его используете) - **несколько версий python**. У меня была такая проблема, только с pygame.
Проверить можно если при открытии файла с разрешением .py есть 2 открытия IDLE.
Так же возможно этот модуль *не поддерживается или что-то типа того*.

Answer (score 0):

Для Python надо брать установщик PyQt соответствующей версии.
Например, у меня для Python 3.5 подошел установщик PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x32-2.exe. Ну и не забыть про одинаковую разрядность обоих сборок.