# Отладка по WiFi

Tags: android, android-adb

До недавних пор у меня была `ОС Windows 10`. И отладку я делал по `ВайФай`, получал путь к `adb` в папке `platform-tools` > `adb connect...` Проект лежал в Диске `D:`, а `platform-tools` в Диске `C:`. И все работало корректно.

И вот недавно установил `Windows 7`. Все файлы в на своих местах. Но когда я пытаюсь перейти к `platform-tools`, типа `cd C:\Users\...\...\sdk\platform-tools` ничего не меняется, то есть, я в том же диске `D:\AndroidProjects`, директория не меняется.

Но если, тот же проект перенести в диск `С:` и доступ к `adb` открывается.

В чем может быть проблема, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Попробуйте cd **/D** C:\Users\...\...\sdk\platform-tools. А вообще проще в переменные окружения (в PATH) добавить %sdk% и %sdk%\platform-tools

Comment: Первый вариант помогло. В ответ перенесите, галку поставлю. А насчет второго. Не совсем понял, как в окружение добавить, не подскажете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для смены директории вместе со сменой диска следует использовать ключ **/D**

```
cd /D C:\Users\...\...\sdk\platform-tools
```

Лучше добавить пути к sdk и sdk\platform-tools в PATH (т.е. пути, по которым вы переходите через cd). См. здесь [Как добавить в переменную окружения PATH путь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153628) Тогда adb и проч будут доступны без смены директории, в частности из вашей d:\AndroidProjects.