# Проблема с библиотекой pyrtlsdr

Tags: python

Скачал и установил библиотеку pyrtlsdr (по ссылке https://github.com/roger-/pyrtlsdr) в python 3.6. Попробовал первый пример (Simple way to read and print some samples). Понял что не достает еще исполняемого файла rtlsdr.dll (у меня Винда 7-я). Перешел с вышеуказанной страницы по рекомендуемой ссылке https://github.com/librtlsdr/librtlsdr/releases. А вот где его искать этот исполняемый файл? Покопал архивы, нету. Где его искать? И потом куда его бросать?

Comment: https://github.com/librtlsdr/librtlsdr/releases/download/v0.7.0/librtlsdr-0.7.0-13-gc79d-x64.zip ?

Comment: Все распаковать в папку rtlsdr ?

Comment: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee123/fa12/rtl_sdr.html

Comment: Свисток сам работает на компе через прогу HDSDR. То есть дрова стоят.

Comment: Кстати библиотека pyrtlsdr  устанавливается  в винде в пайчарме  командой  pip install pyrtlsdr  ?

Comment: Скинул я все файлы из архива в папку rtlsdr. Не помогло, таже ошибка вылетает. Как быть?

Comment: укажите error traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rashid/PycharmProjects/sdr/1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rtlsdr import RtlSdr
  File "C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rtlsdr\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .librtlsdr import librtlsdr

Comment: File "C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rtlsdr\librtlsdr.py", line 41, in <module>
    librtlsdr = load_librtlsdr()
  File "C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rtlsdr\librtlsdr.py", line 36, in load_librtlsdr
    raise ImportError('Error loading librtlsdr. Make sure librtlsdr '\
ImportError: Error loading librtlsdr. Make sure librtlsdr (and all of its dependencies) are in your path

Answer (score 1):

Распакуйте содержимое https://github.com/librtlsdr/librtlsdr/releases/download/v0.7.0/librtlsdr-0.7.0-13-gc79d-x64.zip (для Python 64-bit на Windows 64-bit) в директорию, которая указана в переменной окружения `PATH` или добавьте путь к DLLs к `PATH`.

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне найти директорию, которая указана в переменной окружения PATH ? Я в программировании новичек.

Comment: @Rashid-s, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153628/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-path-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Вот что я нашел C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\

Comment: я так понимаю архив распокавать в  C:\Users\Rashid\‌​AppData\Local\Progra‌​ms\Python\Python36\      ?

Comment: Или в  C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scrip‌​ts\  ?

Answer (score 0):

Что-то получилось. В Пайчарме мне выдало

```
[-0.00392157-0.00392157j -0.00392157-0.00392157j -0.00392157-0.00392157j]
Found Rafael Micro R820T tuner
[R82XX] PLL not locked!
```

Comment: Допишите, что именно сделали, что помогло - на случай если у кого-то возникнет подобная проблема.