# Как открыть запустить на windows файл .py

Tags: python

[image: как запустить?]

Имеется такой файл, скачал с официального сайта python 3.7.2 установил, пытался используя инфу в инете запустить не получилось. Должно запускаться как на скрине ниже [image: должно так]

Comment: вы вводите "python code.py"? и что происходит после ввода?

Comment: Открываю директорию python и запускаю python.exe, в это командное окно переношу файл, который хочу запустить и жму Enter
https://imgur.com/4pb2bRC

Comment: Не надо  запускать python.exe. Просто в командной строке (CMD）наберите `python code.py`

Comment: В скриншоте в первой строке написано, как запускать. Можно и обычным двойным кликом, как любую другую программу.

Comment: если открывать двойным кликом, она открывается и сразу закрывается

Answer (score 2):

Вы написали

```
C:\Users\Malzeriy\Desktop\prntscrScraper—master\code.py
```

*после запуска интерпретатора Питона* (командой `Python`), что можно узнать потому, что вы написали это, когда вы увидели

```
>>>
```

Это неправильно - не ожидался *файл*, но *команда Питона* (например `print(2 + 3)`).

Закройте это окно, снова запустите командную строку. Tеперь нет `>>>`, но путь к *актуальной папке*, например `C:\Users\Malzeriy>`). Напишите

```
python C:\Users\Malzeriy\Desktop\prntscrScraper—master\code.py
```

Всё вместе это может теперь выглядеть так:

```
C:\Users\Malzeriy>python C:\Users\Malzeriy\Desktop\prntscrScraper—master\code.py
```

---

*Примечание:*

Но лучше всего перенести файл `code.py` *прямо в папку, которую вы видите после запуска командной строки* - в моем примере в папку `C:\Users\Malzeriy` - потому что после этого можете просто написать

```
python code.py
```

сразу после запуска командной строки, когда вы увидите

```
C:\Users\Malzeriy>
```

т.е. всё вместе будет выглядеть так:

```
C:\Users\Malzeriy>python code.py
```

---

*Примечание 2:*

Когда после команды

```
python code.py
```

получите

> "python" не является внутренней или внешней
>   командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

обнаружите, в которой папке у вас инсталлирован Питон. Например, у меня он в папке
 `C:\Program Files\Python37`.

*Спешное, разовое решение теперь такое:*

Еще перед командой python code.py напишите:

```
path C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python37
```

так что всё вместе будет выглядеть так:

```
C:\Users\Malzeriy>path C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python37

C:\Users\Malzeriy>python code.py
```

Но лучшее, постоянное решение состоит в добавлении строки
`C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python37;`
в начало или конец переменной окружения `path` - см. [Как добавить путь в переменную окружения %PATH% на Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/153633/233990).

Comment: https://imgur.com/Rb8sen6 - запуск как вы сказали в первом методе; 
 https://imgur.com/s6Ih4j3 - я перенёс файл code.py в `C:\Users\Malzeriy>`

Comment: @ВадимЯнущик насчет того, что python не является внутренней или внешней командой, вам надо добавить в системную переменную path путь до python.exe - ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153628/… . Это нужно для того, чтобы Windows знала где находится python.exe

Comment: Я добавил *Примечание 2* к моему ответу.