# Работа через консоль с PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Установил себе `PostgreSQL`. Хочу создать базу данных, в консоли пишу `createdb bookstore`, выдает ошибку `createdb : Имя "createdb" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.`. Погуглил и нашел только что `createdb` команда будет доступна после установки `PostgreSQL` на вашем компьютере. Но я установил же `PostgreSQL`, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Какая у вас операционная система?

Comment: У меня установлена Windows

Comment: Тогда вам надо либо полностью указывать путь к createdb - `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\bin\createdb.exe` (или куда у вас там именно установлена СУБД), либо добавить подкаталог `bin` каталога установки СУБД в переменную окружения `PATH`.

Comment: Как второй вариант реализовать? Можно инструкцию, или своими словами

Comment: Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/153633/204271).

Comment: Я добавил `bin` в `path` и пробовал так же указал полный путь `E:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\bin\createdb.exe bookstore`, но ошибка осталась `E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\bin\createdb.exe : Имя "E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\bin\createdb.exe" не распознано как имя
командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и
 правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.`

Comment: Консоль после добавления пути в PATH перезапустили?

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо