# Генерация документации

Tags: python

Есть класс, для которого преподаватель сказал мне сгенерировать документацию любыми средствами. Какой из них самый простой? Ибо у меня правда нет времени разбираться. Я пробовал pydoc,но не пойму где прописывать `pydoc -w module_name`. Если в консоли Питона, то не работает. Если в командной строке, то пишет "pydoc не является внутренней или внешней командой".
Вот код моей задачки на всякий случай.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D  

class Game:
    """
    Класс для игры в Крестики-Нолики
    """
    X = "X"
    O = "O"
    EMPTY = " "
    NUM_SQUARES = 9
    TIE = "TIE"
    xCircle = [0.5,1.5,2.5,0.5,1.5,2.5,0.5,1.5,2.5]
    yCircle = [2.5,2.5,2.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]
    radius = 0.4
    fill =False
    xLine1 = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]
    yLine1 = [[2,3],[2,3],[2,3],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]
    xLine2 = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]
    yLine2 = [[3,2],[3,2],[3,2],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]]
    color = 'k'
    xLine3 = [[0,3],[0,3],[0,3],[0.5,0.5],[1.5,1.5],[2.5,2.5],[0,3],[0,3]]
    yLine3 = [[2.5,2.5],[1.5,1.5],[0.5,0.5],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[0,3]]
    colorWin = 'r'
    fig = plt.figure()    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
    color = 'k'

    def setting(self):
        """
        Отображает пустую игровую доску на экране.
        """           
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
        self.ax.set_xticks([1,2,3])
        self.ax.set_yticks([1,2,3])
        self.ax.tick_params(axis='both', left='off', top='off', right='off', bottom='off', labelleft='off', labeltop='off', labelright='off', labelbottom='off')
        self.ax.grid()
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.1)
    def ask_yes_no(self,question,error):
        """
        Задаёт вопрос с ответом 'Да' или 'Нет'.
        """
        response = None
        while response not in ("y", "n"):
            response = input(question).lower()
            if response!="y" or response!="n":
                print(error)
        return response


    def ask_number(self,question, low, high,error):
        """
        Просит ввести число из диапазона
        """
        response = None
        while response not in range(low, high):
            response = input(question)
            try:
               response = int(response)
               if response<low or response>high-1:
                   print(error)
            except ValueError:
               print(error)
        return response


    def pieces(self):
        """
        Определяет принадлежность перового хода.
        """
        go_first = self.ask_yes_no("Играть крестиками? (y, n): ","\nНекорректный ввод. Попробуйте еще раз!\n")
        if go_first == "y":
            print("\n Вы играете кректиками.")
            human = self.X
            computer = self.O
        else:
            print("\n Вы играете ноликами")
            computer = self.X
            human = self.O
        return computer, human


    def new_board(self):
        """
        Создаёт новую игровую доску.
        """
        board = []
        for square in range(self.NUM_SQUARES):
            board.append(self.EMPTY)
        return board


    def display_board(self,board):
        """
        Отображает игровую доску на экране.
        Рисует крестики и нолики.
        """
        for i in range(self.NUM_SQUARES):
            if (board[i]!=self.EMPTY):
                if (board[i]==self.X):
                    line1 = Line2D(self.xLine1[i], self.yLine1[i],color=self.color)
                    line2 = Line2D(self.xLine2[i], self.yLine2[i],color=self.color)
                    self.ax.add_line(line1)
                    self.ax.add_line(line2)
                    plt.draw()
                    plt.pause(0.1)
                if (board[i]==self.O):
                    self.ax.add_artist(plt.Circle((self.xCircle[i], self.yCircle[i]), self.radius, color=self.color, fill=self.fill))
                    plt.draw()
                    plt.pause(0.1)
    def linewin(self,combinationwin):
        """
        Отображает игровую доску на экране.
        Рисует линию при чьей-либо победе.
        """
        if combinationwin!=None:
            line = Line2D(self.xLine3[combinationwin], self.yLine3[combinationwin],color=self.colorWin)
            self.ax.add_line(line)
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.1)
    def legal_moves(self,board):
        """
        Создаёт список доступных ходов.
        """
        moves = []
        for square in range(self.NUM_SQUARES):
            if board[square] == self.EMPTY:
                moves.append(square)
        return moves


    def winner(self,board):
        """
        Определяет победителя в игре.
        """
        WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                       (3, 4, 5),
                       (6, 7, 8),
                       (0, 3, 6),
                       (1, 4, 7),
                       (2, 5, 8),
                       (0, 4, 8),
                       (2, 4, 6))
        for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
            if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != self.EMPTY:
                winner = board[row[0]]
                return winner,WAYS_TO_WIN.index(row)
        if self.EMPTY not in board:
            return self.TIE, None
        return None


    def human_move(self,board, human):
        """
        Получает ход человека
        """
        legal = self.legal_moves(board)
        move = None
        while move not in legal:
            move = self.ask_number("Твой ход. Выбери одно из полей (0 - 8):", 0, self.NUM_SQUARES,"\nНекорректный ввод.Нужно ввести только число от 0 до 8!\n")

            if move not in legal:
                print("\nЭто поле уже занято. Выбери другое.\n")
        return move


    def computer_move(self,board, computer, human):
        """
        Делает ход за компьютерного противника.
        """
        board = board[:]
        BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)

        print("Я выберу поле номер", end = " ")
        for move in self.legal_moves(board):
            board[move] = computer
            if self.winner(board) == computer:
                print(move)
                return move
            board[move] = self.EMPTY

        for moves in self.legal_moves(board):
            board[move] = human
            if self.winner(board) == human:
                print(move)
                return move
            board[move] = self.EMPTY

        for move in BEST_MOVES:
            if move in self.legal_moves(board):
                print(move)
                return move

    def next_turn(self,turn):
        """
        Осуществляет переход хода.
        """
        if turn == self.X:
            return self.O
        else:
            return self.X


    def congrat_winner(self,the_winner, computer, human):
        """
        Поздравляет победителя игры.
        """
        if the_winner == computer:
            print("Вы проиграли!")
        elif the_winner == human:
            print("Вы выиграли!")
        elif the_winner == self.TIE:
            print("Ничья!")

    def main(self):
        """
        Основная функция, которая вызывает все остальные.
        """        
        computer, human = self.pieces()
        self.setting()
        turn = self.X
        board = self.new_board()
        while not self.winner(board):
            if turn == human:
                move = self.human_move(board, human)
                board[move] = human
            else:
                move = self.computer_move(board, computer, human)
                board[move] = computer
            self.display_board(board)
            turn = self.next_turn(turn)
        the_winner,combinationwin =self.winner(board)
        self.linewin(combinationwin)
        self.congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human)
plt.ion()
# запуск программы
clas=Game()
clas.main()
input("Нажмите Enter, чтобы выйти.")
plt.close()
```

Comment: Можно попробовать `python -m pydoc -w module_name` в командной строке.

Comment: @insolor  а где это прописывать?

Comment: В командной строке

Comment: @insolor python не является внутренней или внешней командой... Мне прописывать в области видимости эту папку C:\Users\andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37?

Comment: @insolor Запустилось, спасибо. Можно еще тогда вопрос вот например переменные в классе (например NUM_SQUARES = 9) их как правильно документировать? Также рядом с ними справа писать в тройных кавычках?

Comment: Скорее всего нет. pydoc берет или докстринг (строку в начале модуля, функции, класс и т.д.) или комментарий, опять же в начале модуля/функции/класса. Документация обычно описывает интерфейс модуля (например что каждая функция делает, какие входные параметры, что функция возвращает). Локальные переменные извне функции недоступны, по идее их вообще нет смысла документировать.

Comment: [Как добавить путь в переменную окружения %PATH% на Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153628/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-path-%D0%BD%D0%B0-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Python должен быть прописан в системной переменной PATH. Я не будут здесь описывать как это сделать, это не касается сути вопроса.
2. В командной строке выполнить команду `python -m pydoc -w .\test.py`.

   `.\` означает, что файл находится в текущей папке, где запущена командная строка. Если будет писать, что файл не существует (`file '.\\test.py' does not exist`), то прописываете полный путь к файлу (`python -m pydoc -w c:\directory\test.py`).

   Если после `-w` указать имя без слешей, то это будет считаться именем модуля (который, например, можно внутри своей программы импортировать через `import`).

   Если все успешно, напишет, что создан файл html (`wrote test.html`, например).

Например, файл test.py с таким содержимым:

```
"""Some documentation on the module"""


def test(something):
    """Some text"""
    pass
```

Выполняем `python -m pydoc -w .\test.py`, получится html файл такого вида:

[image: Скриншот]

По поводу документации локальных переменных, pydoc использует для генерации документации или docstring (строку прямо в начале модуля/класса/функции), или блок комментариев перед классом/функцией или в начале модуля:

> For modules, classes, functions and methods, the displayed
>   documentation is derived from the docstring (i.e. the `__doc__`
>   attribute) of the object, and recursively of its documentable members.
>   If there is no docstring, pydoc tries to obtain a description from the
>   block of comment lines just above the definition of the class,
>   function or method in the source file, or at the top of the module
>   (see [inspect.getcomments()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcomments)).

[Скудная документация по pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html)