# Запуск Kotlin кода без IDE

Tags: kotlin

относительно недавно начал изучать Kotlin и все это время запускал код в `IntelliJ IDEA`. А пока я пишу такие простенькие программки мне бы не хотелось еще прибегать к компилятору в `ide`, я подумал, если kotlin язык основанный на java, а простенький java код можно скомпилировать с `javac`, то наверное можно так же сделать и с kotlin, погуглив я не нашел нормального ответа и задаю свой вопрос здесь. **Как скомпилировать простенький код написанный на Kotlin без IDE?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Компиляция Kotlin из командной строки. Пошаговая инструкция:

1. Загрузить компилятор.
   Найти последнюю версию можно [здесь](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/latest). На момент написания ответа последней является версия 1.3.61 (Update 1.4.32)
2. Распаковать компилятор в отдельную папку, добавить bin директорию в переменную окружения PATH. Об этом можно почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153628/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-path-%D0%BD%D0%B0-windows). Bin содержит скрипты, необходимые для сборки и запуска кода на Windows, OS X и Linux.

Другой вариант установки компилятора: Если используете OS X, Linux, Cygwin, FreeBSD или Solaris (возможно, и другие UNIX - системы), то можно использовать [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/).

Запускаем в терминале:

```bsh
$ curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
```

Затем следуем инструкциям. Потом потребуется открыть новое окно терминала и установить Kotlin с помощью команды:

```bsh
$ sdk install kotlin
```

---

Теперь кратко о создании и запуске простого приложения.

1. Создаем файл - hello.kt со следующим кодом:

   ```
   fun main(args: Array<String>) {
       println("Hello, World!")
   }
   ```
2. Компилируем, используя командную строку:

   ```bsh
   $ kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
   ```

   Подробнее о флагах компиляции можно почитать в мане:

   ```bsh
   $ kotlinc -help
   ```
3. Запускаем приложение:

   ```bsh
   $ java -jar hello.jar
   ```

Более подробно о других вариантах установки компилятора, компиляции библиотек, запуске kotlin - скриптов и прочем можно узнать на соответствующей [странице](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) документации.

Comment: хм, а я ведь смотрел в документации, видимо проглядел

Comment: Хорошо бы основное в ответ перенести. Ответы- ссылки у нас не приветствутются.