# Где можно протестить язык

Tags: kotlin

Хотелось бы узнать, где можно протестить язык kotlin.

Например, чтобы потестить работу javascript нужен браузер и блокнот.

А что нужно для kotlin?

Где можно новичку написать мини код, затем посмотреть как он работает.

Что-то вроде песочницы.

Comment: https://play.kotlinlang.org

Comment: Хотелось бы офлайн(((

Comment: Типа браузера и блокнота, как в javascript.

Comment: Офлайн - ставите kotlin, сохраняете файл как скрипт с расширением .kts, запускаете, результат просто в консоли.

Comment: Запускать файл с расширением kts в браузере?

Comment: Как exe файлы??

Comment: Из cmd (или терминала) `kotlinc -script foo.kts`

Comment: Простите за нубство, а что такое терминал)?

Comment: Черное окошко, в которое вводятся команды

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запуск Kotlin кода без IDE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1083944/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-kotlin-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-ide)

Comment: Блокнот и компилятор -- это тот минимум что вам нужен. Компилятор запускается из командной строки.

Answer (score 2):

В любом случае нужно установить сам kotlin.

Дальше из командной строки (`cmd` под windows или терминал на других системах) запускаете `kotlinc` без параметров - запустится в интерактивном режиме ([REPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL)), просто вводите по одной команды, нажимаете Enter - команда выполняется:

[image: REPL]

Еще вариант, в Visual Studio Code ставите плагин "Code Runner"  ([formulahendry.code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)), сохраняете код в файл (kt или kts - если kts, то будет работать как скрипт без функции main), запускаете с помощью кнопки "Run code":

[image: vscode]

Пример с файлом kts (kotlin script):

[image: kotlin script]

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, поставить Android Studio, а приложение запускать или на своем телефоне (если есть), или в эмуляторе.

Comment: В android studio можно посмотреть на работу своего мини кода.

Comment: Для этого всяких плагинов не нужно?

Comment: @Человек вроде бы не нужно. В любом случае вы можете производить запуск своего приложения с телефона (отладка по USB),

Comment: Спасибо у меня еще возник один вопрос.

Comment: Многие новички предпочитают тестить kotlin без ide. Почему? C ide же лучше да?

Comment: @Человек скорее всего потому что запуск IDE не очень сочетается со словом "быстро"

Comment: Зачем Android studio? есть же  intellij idea

Comment: Чем intellij лучше Android Studio?

Comment: Она не лучше, она многоцелевая. AS это по сути IDEA заточенная для Андроид разработки. Сама же IDEA может быть использована для разработки под любую платформу. Котлин же мультиплатформенный язык: JVM/Android/Web/Native. IDEA и есть родная среда разработки на Котлине. Она сама на нем написана.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на то, что попробовать язык можно [тут](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt), [тут](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS40LjEwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS4gXG4gKiBwbGF5LmtvdGxpbmxhbmcub3JnIFxuICovXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHByaW50bG4oXCJIZWxsbywgd29ybGQhISFcIilcbn0ifQ==) да и вообще, запрос `kotlin online try` дает достаточно результатов...

Comment: Хотелось бы оффлайн.

Comment: Ну тогда ответ выше, про установку студии итд.