# Как запускать файлы Kotlin?

Tags: файлы, kotlin

Всем привет! Я начала изучать Kotlin. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно запустить .kt файл из проводника?

P.S. У меня Windows 10

Comment: А JDK & JVM здесь причем? Вы спрашиваете про Kotlin

Comment: Но ведь Kotlin- язык программирования, работающий поверх Java Virtual Machine. А с JDK я случайно опечаталась. Но уже исправила. Простите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Вы знаете, как запускать kotlin-файлы?

Comment: Ваш вопрос более относится к метке [visual-studio-code], а с этой средой разработки я не работал.

Comment: Но ведь я спрашивала не про vs code, а про то, как можно запустить kotlin-файлы из проводника.

Comment: Два раза нажимаете кнопкой мыши по файлу или Enter на клавиатуре, если для файла установлены ассоциации, он откроется в подходящем редакторе, если ассоциации не установлены вам виндовс предложит открыть другими способами, и выберите там ваш используемый редактор, можно "Блокнот"

Comment: Это чтобы редактировать файл. А как его запустить?

Comment: [Если вы про естественную компиляцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1083944/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-kotlin-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-ide?rq=1)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: В будущем-употребляйте слово "компиляция", когда это нужно

Comment: Поняла. Простите, если немного неясно задала вопрос. Просто я новичок в stackoverflow и в программировании :)

Comment: Просто python-файлы можно запускать без компиляции, и я думала, что и в kotlin также.

Comment: Можно и Kotlin, но немного другой (.kts файлы) https://www.danielebonaldo.com/kotlin-script/

Comment: Поняла, спасибо!

Answer (score 9):

Файл .kt никак не запустить, потому что это простой текстовый файл. Чтобы запустить, его нужно сначала скомпилировать в байт-код. Например

```
kotlinc MyProgram.kt -d MyProgram.jar
```

А потом запускать как обычный jar

```
java -jar MyProgram.jar
```

Можно скомпилировать, добавив в файл среду исполнения (но увеличится размер конечного файла). Тогда должно и из проводника через двойной клик запускаться

```
kotlinc MyProgram.kt -include-runtime -d MyProgram.jar
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Это то, что нужно!

Comment: А jar-файл можно запустить не из командной строки, а из проводника?

Comment: добавил в вопрос (хотя не проверял сам)

Comment: Ясно. Надеюсь, что работает :)

Answer (score 2):

Если надо протестировать один файл или блок я использую сервис:
https://play.kotlinlang.org/

Довольно удобный сервис.

Comment: Также можно сразу перетянуть файл в окно браузера когда у вас открыт данный сервис