# Помогите плиз (Python, windows)

Tags: python, windows, ос

Сразу к делу:

> Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог запускать свою программу через консоль. Мне нужно писать вот, что:

```
python C:\%Путь%\python-admin.py --all %И указывать где хочу сделать проект%
```

Как мне так сделать, чтобы я мог просто в консоли написать:

```
python-admin --all %путь%
```

Помогите плиз

Если что, то вот код:

```
import sys,os
if sys.argv[1] == "--all":
    now_path= sys.argv[2]
    project_name= sys.argv[3]
    os.mkdir(now_path+'\\'+project_name)
    os.mkdir(now_path+'\\'+project_name+'\\DATA')
    open(now_path+'\\'+project_name+"\\run.bat",'w').write("echo This BAT file. He started main.py\npython main.py")
    open(now_path+'\\'+project_name+"\\main.py",'w').write('#Это  файл, созданный с помощью newproject.py\n\n\ndef say_hello(name):\n\tprint(f"Hi, {name}")\n\nif __name__ == "__main__":\n\tsay_hello("Обэма")')


else:os.system("Error>>Used not right arguments>>open_arguments>>#^%[--all]%^#")
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно [добавить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/153628/415967) путь к вашей программе в PATH переменную среды.
После этого она будет доступна из консоли повсеместно.

Также чтобы программа могла запускаться как самостоятельный скрипт, она должна иметь точку входа:

```
if __name__ == __main__:
    # тело программы
```