# Почему не импортируется модуль discord.py?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Я пишу в VS code и не могу импортировать библиотеку discord.py.

Я прописываю в терминале `pip install discord.py`.
Вот ошибка:

```
pip : Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания
 имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pip install discord
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Метод `pip` что-ли не работает в VS code?
Как можно тогда установить библиотеки?

Comment: А вы не пробовали ввести данную команду прямо в cmd? Может в только самой VSC эта ошибка.

Comment: @Ma3rX это powershell такую ошибку выдает. cmd скорее всего аналогичную ошибку будет писать. Нужно добавить папку python/scripts в переменную окружения PATH.

Comment: @insolor как это можно сделать? не разбираюсь в этом...

Comment: @ШпеньковКирилл вот тут (для Win7 инструкция, но суть та же и под Win10): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/153628 Только еще путь до python/scripts нужно найти. Можно еще попробовать переустановить python с установкой галки "add to environment variables" (если она не была включена при установке).

Comment: @insolor теперь `pip` заработало. когда я прописываю `pip install discord.py` он устанавливает модуль, но когда я запускаю программу, пишет что модуль не найден...

Что делать? Мой дс если надо: `TT | S_Smerch#2902`

Comment: Значит у вас несколько версией Python, и вы запускаете не той версией, в которую установили модуль. Ну либо действительно виртуальное окружение не то, как вам под вашим новым вопросом написали.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать `python3 -m pip -V`. Если вернёт версию pip'а, то пиши не `pip install discord.py`, а `pip install discord`

Если не вернёт версию, то скачай установщик питона (https://python.org) и при установке выбери пункт `Добавить Python в PATH` (или что-то подобное), а также убедись что выбрать пункт что-то типа `Установить pip` (найдёшь)))

(Когда будешь писать код пиши `import discord` а не discord.py (discord.py - вспомогательная библиотека для discord))